# JavaScript - redirect to other page if password is incorrect

Tags: javascript, passwords

What I want is use another script replace the "alert('That Is Correct!')" which can make it directly open the webpage rather then come up with alert first.

```
if (password === pass1)
    alert('That Is Correct!');
else
    window.location="SITE-LINK";
</script>
```

Note: this script is for when open a page come up with asking password, I just want when the password is right it will continue opening the page, rather than alert message or open a certain page. Because this script is for a template, so it will open many different address.

Comment: Please be aware that anyone can read the source code of your page. They'll be able to see both your password and the link.

Comment: yes, I got that, it just for a basic protect, thanks for your notice.

Comment: Moreover, if they disable javascript, your page won't be protected at all. Would you like a simple, but more secure solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just invert the logic.**

```
if (password != pass1)  
    window.location="SITE-LINK"; 
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, this script is for when open a page come up with asking password, I just want when the password is right it will continue opening the page, rather than open a specify page. because this script is for a template, so it will open many different address. Thanks again!

Comment: This looks like what you want - when the password is correct, the user won't see anything. When it is not correct, they'll be redirected to 'site-link' - which can show 'password incorrect'.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, when the password *is* correct, open the address 'SITE-LINK'? If so, this will work.

```
if (password === pass1) {
    window.location="SITE-LINK";
} else {
    alert('Password is not correct');
}
```

Comment: sorry, this script is for when open a page come up with asking password, I just want when the password right it will continue opening the page, rather than open a specify page. because this script is for a template, so it will open many different address. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the logical check

```
if(password!==pass1)
    window.location="SITE-LINK";
```

Comment: this script is for when open a page come up with asking password, I just want when the password is right it will continue opening the page, rather than alert message or open a certain page. because this script is for a template, so it will open many different address.